# How to create Alfresco Share Java-backed media viewer?

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, surf, alfresco-share

I have investiagted Alfresco [media-viewers](https://github.com/share-extras/media-viewers) project and also read a lot of [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/index.jsp) on WebScripts.

My idea is to create a Java-backed viewer for the Alfresco Share.

The underlying Java code will be a bit complicated - it has to handle additional URLs to load own resources form the bundle to use them.

The ideal solution is to integrate Java code as [Spring Controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) and handle URL mapping with [*@RequestMapping*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) annotation (or through servlet-mapping xml node).

If someone know how [Programming with Surf](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fsurf-fwork-intro.html) can be used in this case it also would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using CMIS to access the Alfresco resource? If your Java runtime will run in a separate process than the Alfresco installation (or on a separate machine) then the CMIS interface would let you do that.

You would write your Spring controller inside a Java web application and then access the documents and metadata using CMIS.

Take a look at Apache Chemistry. which is the CMIS client reference implementation.

Comment: I had not. Thank you I'll check it and tell if it works.

Comment: If you're looking at an even shorter shortcut, take a look at the CMIS workbench. It's an open-source Swing application that uses CMIS to browse content repositories, so you could re-use a lot of that code to give yourself a head-start.

Comment: Thanks, I've just used [this](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html) guide, it was enough.
But I'm still interesting in a way to integrate my application as a Spring bean with own request map.